# How do statements in SQL correlate with C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I have created a database and i have linked it with a Windows Form Application
in Visual Studio and it is written in Visual C#. I am curious to know whether or not the buttons that i have added in the windows form application will correspond with 
the statements that are written in SQL .[image]

Will I need to implement code in the backend of SQL or C# or just one of the two.

Comment: You would need to write code. Check some tutorials. What and how you write depends on what you have used. There are also some controls with code ready provided you set the properties. Just browse beginner tutorials.

Comment: Write code in c# to read and write to your database.

Comment: Oddly, there are ways to use Visual Studio to auto-generate a lot of the code you'd need, like the Servers window, and SqlDataAdapter from the ToolBox window (I think, it's been a while).  People often find that when they need to do something that's not simple cookie-cutter forms, that they NEED to start writing code.  p.s.Good screenshot, told us a lot about what you were really asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using something called **Entity Framework**, which can be installed if you right-click the project name and choose to **Manage NuGet packages**.

This will set up a framework for you so that you don't have to write any C# code connecting your form with your database. It is some what easy to use because it creates *Table Adapters* which makes the connection from a table in your database to your code, an example would be:

```
var myTableAdapter = new myDatabase_TableAdapters.myTableTableAdapter();
System.Data.DataTable myDataTable = myTableAdapter.GetData();
```

Now you have the data from your table in the SQL database in a DataTable and you have your TableAdapter as a connection between the two.

Say you want to take input from your users, then for our example consider the data comes from your text boxes then you could do something like:

```
string vehicleRegNum = vehicleRegNumTextBox.Text,
    make = makeTextBox.Text,
    engineSize = engineSizeTextBox.Text,
    dateReg = dateRegTextBox.Text,
    rentPerDay = rentPerDayTextBox.Text;
bool avail = availCheckBox.Checked;
myTableAdapter.Insert(vehicleRegNum, make, engineSize, dateReg, rentPerDay, avail);
```

This **.Insert** will add this data to your database (Here I am assuming all the text boxes go to one table in your database and that the order is as I have given them).

So in general,

- Get Entity Framework setup in NuGet
- Setup a table adapter from a table in your database
- Update it with user input

A side note: I always like to add a user and date column to these kinds of tables so you can use:

```
string usr = System.Environment.UserName
var entryDate = System.DateTime.Now;
```

**Clarification**: It was pointed out to me by @DanRayson in the comments that I should be more clear about `myDatabase_TableAdapters`. It is not exactly a `TableAdapter`, it is however a `TableAdapter` which *EntityFramework* creates in the background for the user.

Comment: Good answer - just a note though, I don't really know where you got `myDatabase_TableAdapters` from.  What Type is it?  Is it a property on some static thing that EF creates?

Comment: @DanRayson Thanks, from my experience with Entity Framework, I believe that it creates a connection string and allows the user to name the data set of all the tables the user wants to include from the database. By default the name it gives the data set is the name of the database. So I usually leave it as default and it will create the name `myDataBase_TableAdapters` where myDataBase is the name of the database. But, in short it is a `TableAdapter` that EntityFramework creates in the background, so it is not exactly a `TableAdapter` but a `myDataBase_TableAdapter`